# Simple Http alternative for Wireshark

Tags: http, networking, tcp, wireshark, ethernet

In web development, I usually use Firebug. But now I have to use Wireshark to monitor Http requests sent by an Android simulator. Wireshark is a fantastic tool, however it is too fat for what I'm doing, and quite painful to copy/paste the request.

So I'm looking for a simpler alternative on Linux Ubuntu.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wireshark is mostly bloated due to the GUI front-end; however it has a text-version called [`tshark`](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) that uses substantially less memory...  the syntax is very similar to `tcpdump`...

To capture packets sent to and from a webserver on 192.168.12.14, use this...

```
tshark -n -i eth0 tcp and host 192.168.12.14 and port 80
```

Comment: Perfecto ! I can write the result in logs easily. Pretty cool.

Answer (score 3):

You may also consider using ngrep http://ngrep.sourceforge.net/usage.html#http

Comment: I am very happy that I've discovered ngrep. It took up additional 500K on my system, compared to 60MB of tshark. Very simple usage as well: `ngrep -d any port 5984 -W byline`, outputs well formatted traffic from any interface through port 5984.